# Struggling to remove a faulted ZFS pool on Centos 7 using zpool

Tags: centos, filesystems, disk, zfs

I have been doing lots of testing of ZFS recently on a new server.

I'm ready to move this server into production now, but I'm wondering if I can get rid of my old 'faulted' diskpools before I do, for tidyness more than anything else.

so if i run zpool import, I see the following...

```
[root@localhost /]# zpool import
 pool: diskpool
 id: 18370547499919589045
 state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
 see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
config:

    diskpool                              UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      raidz2-1                            UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DNW0  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DG92  ONLINE
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DT6G  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DVJ2  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DLL4  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DLVR  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DLPB  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DAMG  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DCEN  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DA8Q  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DAXK  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840D27A  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DA95  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DFEK  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DA6R  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DSWR  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DNNN  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840CVPT  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DNKW  FAULTED  corrupted data
        ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DNPK  FAULTED  corrupted data
```

I tried to remove 'diskpool' with zpool destroy diskpool, to no avail...

```
[root@localhost /]# zpool destroy diskpool
cannot open 'diskpool': no such pool
```

I've rebooted and done most everything I can think of, but its not letting me bin off this old data.

I know I can essentially ignore it, as once I create my production pool, it will just be old data thats irrelevant, but it would be nice if I could remove it.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Just overwrite the disks (e.g. with zeros) to get rid of *all* data. 2) I hope this was just for testing and you're not intending to run a 20-disk wide vdev in production, which is *way too large*. Split it up into at least 2 vdevs.

Comment: I'm actually running 3 nested vdevs in a 60 disk pool, all RAIDZ2 :)

Comment: ZFS doesn't support nested vdevs. Vdevs can only contain files or disks, not other vdevs. And as I said, a 20 disk wide vdev is *too wide* for a production server.

Comment: To reiterate what @Marco says: 20 drives in a RAIDZ2 vdev is going to have unacceptable rebuild/scrub times, especially given the drives are not just 8 TB each, they're 8 TB and *slow* - at 5900 RPM, they can probably only do about 50-60 IO ops per second. And backups? [RAID is **not** a backup.](http://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup)  You have 60 huge, slow drives and only 6 "parity drives" and no spares. Depending on usage, if it's a general-purpose file store I'd build it with 4+1 RAIDZ (not RAIDZ2) vdevs to better handle smaller-block IO, with 5 spares.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the only disk that remembers the "diskpool" pool is ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DG92, so what you can do is overwrite the label on that disk:

```
# zpool create -f foo ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DG92
# zpool destroy foo
```

That should prevent the "zpool import" command from seeing the long-defunct diskpool. Be careful to make sure that ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840DG92 is not being used by **any other pool** in your system, first.